# Javascript automatically approximates huge integers. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, integer

Javasctipt approximates automatically a huge number like this one 9223372036854775807 to this one: 9223372036854776000

Comment: Numbers in JS are stored as IEEE-754 double floats. Lots of duplicates and answers if looking for “javascript largest integer” or similar.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin (also note BigInt is a new/separate type), https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_numbers.html

Comment: Snap. Closed by my vote alone?! I feel powerful today.